# Under-sink tankless water heater inlet

Tags: plumbing, water, heater, tankless

I'm looking at installing a mini water heater under my kitchen sink for quick usage.  I already have a whole- house tankless water heater in my basement.
I'm trying to avoid having the main unit kick on every time I use the under sink unit.
Can I supply the mini unit with the cold line, and place a tee to supply the cold to the faucet as well,  and cap the existing hot line? Is this how these are designed to be installed?

Comment: What kind of power will you have for it? What kind of flow rate do you want? (Hint: 40A per GPM, we're talking 240V of course).  Or are you referring to a point-of-use *tanked* unit?

Comment: To answer we need to know what is the model, the capacity, the power requirement...

Comment: I'm only wondering about the plumbing aspect.  Are these units typically fed with the the cold line that originally supplies the cold side of the sink faucet?

Comment: "Are these units typically fed with the the cold line that originally supplies the cold side of the sink faucet? "  The answer to that depends on what type of water heater you are looking to use.  Some do...some don't

Comment: If you would cap off the hot line, then you would have a long dead leg which would stagnate and breed bacteria.  But the only way to prevent the main tankless WH from turning on for every small use of hot water is feed the small under counter tank from the cold line. One way to meet these conflicting requirements is to install a separate faucet for the under counter water heater. This used to be done for the small tanks which held water near boiling. This way when you want to fill the sink with hot or warm water you just use the main faucet fed by the main tankless WH.

Comment: Of course, most people have dishwashers and AFIK dishwashers are fed by the hot water system. Would you want the dishwasher to be fed by the small under counter WH or fed by the main tankless WH?

Comment: Do you have suitable power under the sink?  The under sink duplex receptacle for a disposer is often fully switched, i.e., both receptacles switched. Better installations have only one receptacle switched.

Comment: One solution to wanting small amounts of hot water is to get a thermostatted electric kettle or carafe holding 1 ot 2 L of water set up near the sink.

Comment: I would have the dishwasher and hot tap fed by the under sink unit.  I don't have a garbage disposal so I figured on either running the plug to the refrigerator outlet, or running a new branch.  I did see an electric tankless unit that ran on 220v/40 amp, but that would require an entire new circuit with 8 gauge wire from the other end of my house which wouldn't be worth the trouble. If I can figure something to do with the water remaining in the old hot line to the tap I think I'd go the first route.